# using import ogr in Arcgis python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, gdal, ogr, python-window

I need to use import ogr in my python window provided by ArcGIS 10.2, but i can't configure ogr and gdal on my system.

How can I fix this issue and import ogr in my python window provided by ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: Do you mean Python window exactly in ArcMap or do you have standalone script that uses arcpy module?

Comment: i have standalone script which is automatically installed along with arcgis package.